# Preview all Android XML layout files in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, file, layout, preview

Is it possible to preview all Android XML layout files in Eclipse at once?

(I do not think to preview one single layout in different screen resolution, theme or API!)

I have many similar dialog and sometimes I need to preview all layout to find one I need.

Comment: You should give appropriate names to each one of your layout, so you can recognize them just by their names.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a self-contained activity that:

1. Dynamically loads all layout id values
2. Has a touch listener that will cycle through all layouts
3. Shows the current layout name in a short Toast message

**REQUEST:**
*Would be great if someone can suggest a way to add the layout name programmatically to appear over the layout after the view updates.*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    List<Integer> layoutIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Map<Integer, String> layoutNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    int curIdx = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        loadLayoutIds();

        showNext();   
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            showNext();

        return true;
    }

    private void showNext()
    {
        if (curIdx >= layoutIds.size())
            curIdx = 0;

        int layoutId = (int) layoutIds.get(curIdx);

        setContentView(layoutId);

        String msg = layoutNameMap.get(layoutId);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        curIdx++;
    }

    private void loadLayoutIds()
    {
        try
        {
            Class<?> c = R.layout.class;
            Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

            for (Field field : fields) 
            {
                Class<?> t = field.getType();
                if(t == int.class)
                {
                    int layoutId = field.getInt(null);
                    String name = field.getName();

                    // Because /layout folder can have different layout files, 
                    // use some prefix to indicate which files are at the "activity level"
                    // This way the following IF controls which layout files make it in
                    if ( ! name.startsWith("activity_"))
                        continue;

                    Log.d("tag", "cur field = " + name + ", cur layoutId = " + layoutId );
                    layoutIds.add(layoutId);
                    layoutNameMap.put(layoutId, name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}
    }

}
```

*(Add imports, modifiers, exception handlers, etc as needed)*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show them all at once in 1 window. But you can have multiple files open at once.

It is possible to have multiple files next to each other, but also as floating windows.

Like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now, since I transit to Android Studio, I see that there is such functionality. Its called "Navigation Editor" and one can reach it form in main menu:

Tools > Android > Navigation Editor

work exactly what I need. Here is a print screen example:

[image: Navigation Editor example]

Here is only 2 activities, but I have some project that have more than 40 activities, and this help me to find me right one quickly. :)